# Why are the killer robots called necromancers?

Tags: names, raised-by-wolves

In *Raised by Wolves* the religious faction created killer robots that they called necromancers. Why?

A necromancer communicates with the dead. The title seems to have nothing to do with the robots.

Comment: Maybe it's just a name. The Lockheed Starfighter can't fly in space or fight stars.

Comment: "Necromancer" sounds much better than "necromaker."

Comment: As the series is only 3 episodes in, we may be missing relevant information that will be introduced later.

Comment: NATO calls the MiG-23 "Flogger" and the Su-27 "Flanker", and the US A-10 is commonly known as "Warthog"... names need not be consistent with function. At least the "necro" prefix implies something to do with death, making it at least partially consistent.

Answer (score 10):

The most likely answer is someone in charge thought necromancer sounded cool so they named them necromancers.

There are many named weapon systems from missiles called Sidewinders to tanks called Walker Bulldog naming conventions are somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: The F-14 Tomcat shared basically no heritage with an actual cat, tom or otherwise.  The Eurofighter will hopefully never fight Euros.  The Tornado never created a tornado.  The Spitfire, however, did spit fire.

Comment: @Moo - The Eurofighter is a fighter that costs a lot of Euros

Comment: Raised by Wolves feels like a show that tries to include a lot of subtext. That one of our main characters is both "Mother" (life) and a "necromancer" (death) doesn't seem like a flippant choice (though I'll be damned if I know what they're going for just yet). I would be quite surprised if future episodes don't provide *some* explanation for the name. Mother's true nature is being teased as one of the key mysteries of the show (see also: why do the Atheist survivors avert their gaze from necromancers?).

Comment: It is interesting that her eyes are key to her power -- necromancers i think predict things based on talking to dead.

Answer (score 0):

I did not like the name much either but here are two points:

1. Her acoustic weapon: she "talks" to the dead (or soon to be dead) -- dark humor perhaps on the part of the android's developers.
2. That her eyes are central to her powers might be related -- necromancers don't merely chat with the dead: they use the dead to obtain information about the future. This does not explain the name but I think it is related.

BTW, in the Riddick movies, necromongers sounded pretty stupid to me also.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not the name of her model. It is a nickname some of the characters refer to her as but when she hears a character refer to her as a necromancer she is quick to ask that character not to call her that.

Comment: Spoiler(?): "Mother" was constructed as a "necromancer" but was repurposed/"reborn" to a very different role for her mission on Kepler 22b; even if it was a formal model name, she would have had reason to object to the moniker because it wasn't what she was anymore, even if she did revert and use her "necromancer" powers to further her mission on the new world.